# Firebase functions - how to get https trigger with json response

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using firebase cloud function http trigger, we can trigger the function as per below process.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

I'm trying to trigger firebase cloud function with url as input and url returns JSON response. how to use the JSON response in the firebase cloud functions?

Comment: This code can help: exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   const date = moment()
   res.status(200).json({ date: date });
})